# Why my web api is always is unable to execute a HttpGet request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, http-get

I am starting a new web api, where i added a controller **SRDSController**, where i have a **Get** method, returns a string. But unfourtunately, it is not not returning it, the boilerplate asp.net web api code is returning it similarly. Please help

After a lot of google search, i have added
`GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();` in the Global.asax. But still not solved the issue.

The **Global.asax** :

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); 
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
```

The **SRDSController**

```
     [RoutePrefix("srds-data")]
      public class SRDSController : ApiController
    {
    private ISRDSService srdsService = null;
    public SRDSController()
    {
        srdsService = new SRDSService();
    }

    [Route("srds-test")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetTestData()
    {
        return "SRDS is working";
    }

    [Route("get-org-detail")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult GetOrgDetails(SRDSRequest srdsRequest)
    {
        var data = srdsService.GetOrgDetails(srdsRequest.OrgNumbers, srdsRequest.UserName);

        return Ok(data);
    } 
}`
```

As of now, whenever i am running the application, it is starting the application with **http://localhost:59691/Help/**, and it comes up with all the  list of Get & Post Methods.

Feel free to ask any question

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is exactly URL request are you trying to access your Method?

Comment: Whenever i am starting the application, it is redirecting to 404 page

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you may be missing this call:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

This must be done in the Register method of the class WebApiConfig. See [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for more details. Im saying this because you are using Attribute Routing in your action methods.

The reason why the call to help url works its because is being registered when you call RegisterAllAreas.